# How to center an outer div?

Tags: html, css

I have a container div which has other divs and contents within it and I am trying to center the outer div.

For example:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.test {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: green;
}

.outer-test {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-test">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

In the example above, how would I be able to center the div with class of "outer-test"? I have tried to make the display: block and use margin: auto but that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: do you need to center it on both axis ?

Comment: The outer div IS centered, it's just 100% wide. Put a background on it to see,

Comment: `.outer-test {
 width:max-content;   max-width:100%;
  margin: auto;
}` is maybe what you look for ?

Comment: If an answer helped you, then please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: You can use `display: flex` on the `body`

```css
body{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; // Centers in the direction of flex-direction (default is row)
  align-items: center; // Centers in the direction normal to flex-direction
}
.test{
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="outer-test">
    <p>Hello</p>
    <div class="test"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Option 2: You can use a wrapper around your outer div.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
.test {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: green;
}
.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="center">
  <div class="outer-test">
    <p>Hello</p>
    <div class="test"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```